# Which user id do I use for boto3 upload_fileobj?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to figure out how to use the Python boto3 library to upload files and assign permissions while doing so.  I am able to upload a file just fine, but I cannot seem to grant control of it to my IAM user.  In the documentation here https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html#the-extraargs-parameter, it shows the code:

```
s3.upload_file(
    'FILE_NAME', 'BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME',
    ExtraArgs={
        'GrantRead': 'uri="http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"',
        'GrantFullControl': 'id="01234567890abcdefg"',
    }
)
```

In the GrantFullControl string, what does the id refer to?  Is it the

- IAM User name
- IAM User ARN
- AWS Account ID
- Canonical User ID

?  I have tried all of these, and they all fail with the error

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutObject operation: Invalid id
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is apparently the canonical user id.  I got it to work like that; the problem was that I was putting single quotes inside double quotes instead of double quotes inside single quotes.

```
'GrantFullControl': "id='01234567890abcdefg'",  #This doesn't work.

'GrantFullControl': 'id="01234567890abcdefg"',  #This works.
```

Comment: Sidenote: I don't know why I see so many people putting double quotes inside single quotes so often.  This is the only instance I have seen in which the choice hasn't been arbitrary, and it just makes sense that the single quotes would go inside the double quotes.